# Passing data from controller to blade view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to pass data from my controller to blade view. What am I missing?

Controller:

```
    public function getRolesFront(){

        $roles= Role::join(
        'user_roles',
        'roles.id', 
        '=', 
        'user_roles.role_id')
        ->join(
        'users', 
        'user_roles.user_id',
        '=',
        'users.id')
        ->select(
        'user_roles.id AS row_id',
        'user_roles.user_id',
        'roles.name AS name',
        'roles.function AS function',
        'users.name AS user_name',
        'user_roles.role_id')
        ->orderBy('user_roles.user_id')
        ->get();

        return view('users_view', compact($roles));
    }
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/userslist','RoleController@getRolesFront');
```

blade

```
<tr>
  @foreach($roles as $role)
  {{$role->role_id}}
  @endforeach
</tr>
```

the error is:

> Undefined variable: roles (View: C:\laragon\www\ProjectoFinal\resources\views\users_view.blade.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using compact, don't add the actual variable, but rather the string name of the variable that was defined previously in code.

So, **not**:

```
return view('users_view', compact($roles));
```

but rather:

```
return view('users_view', compact('roles'));
```

Comment: do you know how do I send another object to the same view, from a different controller?

Comment: Sure, in the same way - create a method in that other controller, and within that method, store whatever you like in the same `$roles` variable, and use the exact same return statement as above.